# R's hier.part() depends on predictor order

Tags: c, r, glm

I've tried to use the hier.part R package (and it's hier.part() function) to estimate independent contributions of the variables. Suddenly I've experienced a strong dependence on the predictor order.

There is a paper (http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0011698 ) reporting similar behavior for more than 9 predictors. Package's documentation also reports "minor rounding error" for 9-12 predictors. But I've experienced it even in package's example with 4 independent variables.

```
> library(hier.part)
> data(amphipod)
> env1 <- amphipod[,2:5]
> hier.part(amphipod$australis, env1, fam = "binomial",
+           gof = "logLik", barplot=F)$I.perc
              I
fimp   19.74685
fconn  18.24679
densep 25.24765
unseal 36.75871
> hier.part(amphipod$australis, env1[,c(4,3,2,1)], fam = "binomial",
+           gof = "logLik", barplot=F)$I.perc
              I
unseal 16.16072
densep 17.98755
fconn  32.00246
fimp   33.84927
```

In addition, the exact values are not stable between calls. The function uses C code (in partition() call) and at least the  "between calls stability" issue can be attributed to it, because all the relevant R code is deterministic.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the C programming language, so please remove the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: I've added some explanations about the c tag.

Answer (score 0):

this time, your problem is not shown in my R. The two I$perc are the same.-Chenxi